# Facing issues in multi project build using gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have gradle multi-project(Java) build. My project structure is like below:

```
Root project 'Parent'
+--- Project ':Child1'
+--- Project ':Child2'
\--- Project ':Child3'
```

**Project description:**
-Child2 is dependent on Child1.
-Child3 is dependent on Child1 and Child2.

Each subproject has its own build.gradle file

build.gradle file of Child2 has below content:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
archivesBaseName = 'xyz'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: project.properties['dependency_jar_path'], include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Child1')
}
```

build.gradle file of Child3 has below content:

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    archivesBaseName = 'abc'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: project.properties['dependency_jar_path'], include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':Child1')
        compile project(':Child2')
    }
```

The problem that I am facing is Child1 and Child2 are compiling fine but Child3 is not compiling

Comment: is child3 dependent on child 1 only. if yes , u need to remove compile project(':Child2')  in gradle of child3

Comment: Can you please post the error that you are facing.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar yes, child3 is dependent on child1 also

Comment: @VarunJain it's failing in :Child3:compileJava

Comment: @FarheenNaaz why are you compiling child2 in child3 related build.gradle

Comment: @MandarDharurkar child3 has dependency on child2. Some java files in child3 are referencing files from child2